# Non-PIE Binary - The executable '<xyz>' is not a Position Independent Executable

Tags: ios, binaryfiles

This response has been received for all recent submissions of iOS applications. "How to fix this" has been covered in several posts. I am more curious as to

- Why this is happening now and not earlier.
- What it means for it to be a PIE binary?
  From wikipedia I gather it has to do with security between various apps, but am not clear on the details, and why this is a new warning in that case.
- Are we risking anything by leaving it as a Non PIE Binary?
  Currently our app supports >= 4.0  iOS, however to build PIE binary, we need to change that to >= 4.3. Thus we have avoided it so far. (on a tangent, are there any/significant number of users on < 4.3 iOS versions?)
- Is there a chance this will become mandatory in the near future?

Answer (score -1):

I believe a Position Independent Executable is a program that can be placed at any memory address and still run. So typically all data is referred to by relative memory addresses. If you tried to refer to a fixed memory address, that memory address might be outside your program entirely if it gets loaded at a different location in memory.

I have no idea what the particular ins and outs of PIE are for iOS.